# how to fix this php json response?

Tags: php, mysql

I get this result from my PHP:

> {"risultato":"1","ris":[{"pda":"763,41","num1":"86,86","num2":"21,18","num3":"178603,201535"}]}

What I need to do if I want to return the result like this instead?

> {"risultato":"1","ris":[{"pda":"763","num1":"86","num2":"21","num3":"178603"},{"pda":"41","num1":"86","num2":"18","num3":"201535"}]}

Here is my PHP code:

```
$stmtcarte = $connection->prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat.pda) as pda, GROUP_CONCAT(concat.num1) as num1,GROUP_CONCAT(concat.num2) as num2, GROUP_CONCAT(concat.num3) as num3  FROM (SELECT pda, num1, num2, num3,  FROM giocatori WHERE categoria=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 ) concat");
    
    $categoria=$categoriaselezionata;
    $stmtcarte->bind_param("s",$categoria);
    $stmtcarte->execute();
    $risultatocarte = $stmtcarte->get_result();
    
    $result=array("risultato"=>"1", "ris"=>"");
    while($rispostacarte=$risultatocarte->fetch_assoc()){
    
    $result['ris']=array($rispostacarte);
    echo json_encode($result);
                  
    }
    $stmtcarte->close();
```

Comment: I'm surprised if you got any result from your MySQL query because you have an extra comma in your subquery there `(SELECT pda, num1, num2, num3,  FROM giocatori ...`. That comma after `num3` will definitely return you an error message.

Comment: the comma was added while I was describing the problem

Comment: Well apart from that, should the result from MySQL returned as each row instead? The way I see it, you're doing `GROUP_CONCAT()` on those columns result which return them in a single row. I don't know much about PHP but I guess the final result from MySQL should be separated by row? So, what if you didn't use `GROUP_CONCAT()`? What will happen?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the answer.  Don't concatenate in the query, then just build the array and let json_encode handle the output.  Also, I don't think he needs the array() around $rispostacarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am SURE there is a `Mysql` approach to your problem, and therefore, definitely, any other direction is not the best idea. But still, I prefer a PHP snippet to get your desired response.

Let's say you have got the `$result` variable exactly as like the way you showed in your question. Here is what I came up with:

```php
<?php
$ris = $result["ris"][0];
$tempRis = [];
foreach ($ris as $key => $value) {
    $explodedArray = explode(",", $value);
    $length = count($explodedArray);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length ; $i++) { 
        $tempRis[$i][$key] = $explodedArray[$i];
    }
}
$result["ris"][0] = $tempRis;
print_r($result);
?>
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [risultato] => 1
    [ris] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pda] => 763
                            [num1] => 86
                            [num2] => 21
                            [num3] => 178603
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [pda] => 41
                            [num1] => 86
                            [num2] => 18
                            [num3] => 201535
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: thank you so much so it's almost perfect, you by chance know how to remove one of the square brackets? {"risultato":"1","ris":[[{"pda":"763","num1":"86","num2":"21","num3":"178603"},{"pda":"41","num1":"86","num2":"18","num3":"201535"}]]}

Comment: SQL solutions aren't always better than scripting solutions.  Each is better for different things.  I don't think I would try to generate a json output using mySQL, especially since you're going to need some scripting language to serve it.  Might as well let php handle the conversion to json, since it's got a built in library that's good at it.

Answer (score 1):

The group_concat is your problem.  Remove it.  All it's going to make you have to do is explode the delimited string to get it into arrays, and then have to reframe everything into a new array of a different structure.

Not sure what that subquery is for.  I think a straight select is going to be all you need.  You wouldn't need the subquery even if you did want to use group_concat, which I don't think you do.

This also doesn't take complicated array handling.  All you have to do is push each row from your result set to the $ris array, because fetch_assoc() is already returning an (associative) array that has the keys and values.

```
$stmtcarte = $connection->prepare("
  SELECT pda, num1, num2, num3  
  FROM giocatori WHERE categoria=? 
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
");
    
$categoria = $categoriaselezionata;
$stmtcarte->bind_param("s",$categoria);
$stmtcarte->execute();
$risultatocarte = $stmtcarte->get_result();
    
$result = array("risultato"=>"1", "ris"=>array());

while($rispostacarte = $risultatocarte->fetch_assoc()){    
  $result['ris'][] = $rispostacarte;                  
}

$stmtcarte->close();
echo json_encode($result);
```

If you are using php >= 5.4, you don't need to use array(). You can use [] instead.  That would change this line:

```
$result = array("risultato"=>"1", "ris"=>array());
```

to this:

```
$result = ["risultato"=>"1", "ris"=>[]];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but so the result would be: {"risultato":"1","ris":[{"pda":"763","num1":"86","num2":"21","num3":"178603"]}{"risultato":"1","ris":[{"pda":"41","num1":"86","num2":"18","num3":"201535"}]}

Comment: You ran the code and that's what it produced?

Comment: Because what you have in your comment isn't valid json, so it would be impossible for json_encode to produce.

Comment: yes, the result is that

Comment: json_encode is incapable of producing invalid json, and json_encode is the only output in the code I provided.  What else is producing output?  Something must be, because json_encode can't produce that string.

Comment: See this working implementation.  Isn't this the correct output?  https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/0f5ecfc8da02ca1b686d3fc8594788d0/php/php8/b5b92cdb69d6cb9d65e59725994516e9/