# how to remove extra square bracket in json format?

Tags: php, mysql

this is my json response:

```
{"risultato":"1","ris":[[{"pda":"788","num1":"83","num2":"10","num3":"207410"},{"pda":"232","num1":"83","num2":"14","num3":"204935"}]]}
```

as you can see there is an extra square bracket, how can I remove it?
the result I would like this:

```
{"risultato":"1","ris":[{"pda":"788","num1":"83","num2":"10","num3":"207410"},{"pda":"232","num1":"83","num2":"14","num3":"204935"}]}
```

php:

```
$stmtcarte = $connection->prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat.pda) as pda, GROUP_CONCAT(concat.num1) as num1,GROUP_CONCAT(concat.num2) as num2, GROUP_CONCAT(concat.num3) as num3 FROM (SELECT pda, num1, num2, num3 FROM giocatori WHERE categoria=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 ) concat");

        $categoria=$categoriaselezionata;
        $stmtcarte->bind_param("s",$categoria);
        $stmtcarte->execute();
        $risultatocarte = $stmtcarte->get_result();
        $numero_giocatori = $risultatocarte->num_rows;
        $result=array("risultato"=>"1", "ris"=>"");
        while($rispostacarte=$risultatocarte->fetch_assoc()){

              $result['ris']=array($rispostacarte);
              $ris = $result["ris"][0];
              $tempRis = [];
              foreach ($ris as $key => $value) {
              $explodedArray = explode(",", $value);
              $length = count($explodedArray);
              for ($i=0; $i < $length ; $i++) { 
              $tempRis[$i][$key] = $explodedArray[$i];
    }
}
            $result["ris][0] = $tempRis;
            echo json_encode($result);
            
              
        }
        $stmtcarte->close();
```

Comment: "Extra" brackets not exists in JSON. Your JSONs (responce and desired) are not equivalent.

Comment: Syntax error here `$result["ris][0]`.

Comment: And remove the `[0]` in `$result["ris"][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple code like:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT pda, num1, num2, num3 
        FROM giocatori WHERE categoria=? 
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 2";

// get DB data using PDO
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$category]);

$risultato = [
    'risultato' => 1,
    'ris'=>[]
];

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $risultato['ris'][] = $row;
}

print_r(json_encode($risultato, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

[Test PHP & MySQL code here](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/0f5ecfc8da02ca1b686d3fc8594788d0/php/php8/e87561f7181730fd713e57e9705f2dce/)

Result:

```
{
    "risultato": 1,
    "ris": [
        {
            "pda": "788",
            "num1": "83",
            "num2": "10",
            "num3": "207410"
        },
        {
            "pda": "232",
            "num1": "83",
            "num2": "14",
            "num3": "204935"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871892/how-to-fix-this-php-json-response/70873797#70873797

Comment: @alessio830 Did either of these (more or less identical) solutions work for you?  They both seem to return the desired output.